# Pop up message when visitor comes from exact url (=redirection)

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I'm planning to change our company name so the main domain name also changes. I would like to show pop up message for visitors who come to new site using "old urls" which are redirected using 301 permanent redirection.

Our website is using wordpress.

Example: Visitor enters www.olddomain.com and gets redirected to www.newdomain.com he sees the pop up message. Those who just use www.newdomain.com shouldn't get that pop up.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Are you OK with passing parameters e.g. redirecting to `/?redirected=1` or `/#redirected`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
add_action('template_redirect','show_popup');
function show_popup(){
   $old = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
   if($old == 'www.olddomain.com'){
       //show popup
   }
}
```

Comment: That won't work for two reasons: `template_redirect` fires too early for you to include any HTML/JS code, and when a 3XX redirect happens, there will be no referrer for a type in/bookmark etc or the referrer will be the page that the user clicked on the link leading to the redirect.